# Strip all non-alphanumeric, spaces and punctuation symbols from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, sanitization

How can I use PHP to strip out all characters that are NOT letters, numbers, spaces, or punctuation marks?

I've tried the following, but it strips punctuation.

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", "", $str);
```

Example:

```
php > echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{P}]/", "", "⟺f✆oo☃. ba⟗r!");
foo. bar!
```

`\p{P}` matches all Unicode punctuation characters (see Unicode [character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)).  If you only want to allow specific punctuation, simply add them to the negated character class.  E.g:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s.?!]/", "", $str);
```

Comment: The second would.  The first allows all punctuation.

Comment: These seem to strip ALL characters :(

Comment: I'm using your first example and this seem to strip all characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Tedd, not sure.  I posted a tested example.  The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) mention a couple caveats.  You have to use PHP after 4.4 or 5.1 (depending on branch), and UTF-8, and the PCRE library has to be compiled with `--enable-unicode-properties`

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to list the punctuation explicitly as there is no shorthand for that (eg `\s` is shorthand for white space characters).

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\-=+\|!@#$%^&*()`~\[\]{};:\'",<.>\/?]/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = trim($str);
$str = trim($str, "\x00..\x1F");
$str = str_replace(array( "&quot;","&#039;","&amp;","&lt;","&gt;"),' ',$str);
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/', ' ', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str); 
$str = trim($str);
$str = preg_replace('/[ ]/', '-', $str);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  It appears to be implementing a different set of rules (different from what the question asks for).

Answer (score 0):

Let's build a multibyte-safe/unicode-safe pattern for this task.

From https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html:

- `\p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language.`
- `\p{Z} or \p{Separator}: any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.`
- `\p{N} or \p{Number}: any kind of numeric character in any script.`
- `\p{P} or \p{Punctuation}: any kind of punctuation character.`
- `[^ ... ]` is a negated character class that matches any character not in the list.
- `+` is a "one or more" quantifier.
- `u` [This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#:%7E:text=(PCRE_UTF8)-,This%20modifier%20turns%20on%20additional%20functionality%20of%20PCRE%20that%20is%20incompatible,Five%20and%20six%20octet%20UTF%2D8%20sequences%20are%20regarded%20as%20invalid.,-%EF%BC%8Badd%20a)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6Zir3))

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{P}]+/u', '', $string);
```