# Remove All these characters

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex: Strip non alpha numeric or punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050352/regex-strip-non-alpha-numeric-or-punctuation)

I want to remove all character but these in a string

Aplha and Numeric and characters @#()-._,

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: common question, please search first.

Comment: [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Also, you're asking strangers to volunteer their time to help you. Take more than 10 seconds to write your question so that it's not full of typos and grammatical errors.